# How to ensure only one entry is True in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm stuck on thinking about implementing a "only one entry might be True for one combination".

A Project has n members (Guards) through an intermediate table.

- every Guard may be member of n Projects
- only one combination of Guard <-> Project is allowed (unique_together)
- a MemberShip might be the 'Main' one (is_main)
- **BUT**: Only one of the memberships may be Main.

Do I oversee something or do I have to implement a custom validation on my own?

To complete this, see the given Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shortname = models.CharField(_('shortname'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Guard, through='ProjectMembership')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['client', 'shortname']


class ProjectMembership(models.Model):
    guard = models.ForeignKey(Guard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(_('is main project'), default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['guard', 'project']
```

Comment: Is `is_main` the main project of a *per* `Guard`, or *per* `Project`, the `'is main project'` seems to suggest that a guard can have multiple projects, but for each `Guard` there is only one `is_main=True`?

Comment: That's correct. Each Guard can have several Projects but only one shoudl be the main one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can work with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) that is filtered:

```
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint, Q

class ProjectMembership(models.Model):
    guard = models.ForeignKey(Guard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(_('is main project'), default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=('guard', 'project'), name='unique_guard'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=('guard',), condition=Q(is_main=True), name='one_main_project_per_guard'),
        ]
```

Here we thus ensure that if we filter `ProjectMembership` for `is_main=True`, that the set of `guard`s is unique, hence a certain `Guard` can only occur once for `is_main`, and this thus means that a `Guard` has *at most* one `Project` for which `is_main` is `True`.

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).